# Different results for round(12.5) on different python versions

Tags: python

When I test the round(x) function in IDLE it works perfectly fine, as it gives the number of 13 when I enter round(12.5). However in my program (see below) it does not do so, as it will round 12.5 down to 12.

What is wrong with my program? Thank you for your help.

My program:

```
import random

interval_begin = 1
interval_end = 50
interval_half = interval_end *0.5
interval_half_to_end = interval_end - interval_half
players_pick = float(input("Pick a number between {} and {}.". format(interval_begin, interval_end) ))
computer_guess = (interval_end)/2
print("Computer guesses {}.".format(computer_guess))
while players_pick != computer_guess:
    if computer_guess < players_pick:
        interval_half /= 2/3
        computer_guess = round(interval_half)
        print("Computer guesses {}.".format(computer_guess))
    else:
        interval_half /= 2
        computer_guess = round(interval_half)
        print("Computer guesses {}.".format(computer_guess))
```

Comment: In idle round(12.5) is also 12.0....

Comment: Editor won't affect functionality of a library

Comment: The two editors may have different versions of python running

Comment: @Marcus.Aurelianus Oh yeah. My bad. Do you know of a solution to my problem?

Comment: what do you want? 12.0 or 13.0. And for other values lets say 1.5 what do you want for a round value. 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Round doesn't work like that in Python 3+:

> For the built-in types supporting `round()`, values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus `ndigits`; **if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice** (so, for example, both `round(0.5)` and `round(-0.5)` are `0`, and `round(1.5)` is `2`). Any integer value is valid for `ndigits` (positive, zero, or negative). The return value is an integer if called with one argument, otherwise of the same type as `number`.

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#round

In Python 2, 0.5 is rounded up, however:

> Return the floating point value `number` rounded to `ndigits` digits after the decimal point. If `ndigits` is omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number. Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus `ndigits`; **if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0** (so, for example, `round(0.5)` is `1.0` and `round(-0.5)` is `-1.0`).

https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#round

So this will be caused by an interpreter version difference.

You should probably also be aware of the limitations of floats: https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues

Comment: I see. Thank you for your explanations. How can I round in the "common" way then?

Comment: You probably need a function such as in Amichai's answer.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: the following can help only if you always want to round up or always down:

```
import math
math.ceil(2.5)  #3
math.floor(2.5  #2
```

This sould work for your case:

```
def myround(n):
    if n * 10 % 10 > 5:
        return math.ceil(n)
    return math.floor(n)
```

Comment: This gives fundamentally different results when doing e.g. `round(2.6)`, where you would indeed expect 3. It's not a drop-in replacement for `round` with slightly different behaviour.

Comment: How can I use it. Just use this code from you and continue with the round(x) function?

Comment: Replace round with ceil and it will work since your code only uses .5's when there are decimals

Comment: yeah good point. i updated my answer to a function that sould help him out

Comment: @thebilly yes. you can add the function myround and replace it with your round

Comment: What do you guys think about this approach?
I import the decimal package (from decimal import *)
and then use round(Decimal()). I figured that that works fine.